# Filter an array of words by an array of single letters it should ONLY contain

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, letter

I currently have two PHP arrays:

1. `array('a','c','r','r')`
2. `array('carr','car','arc','ra','c','abc','do','aa','rr')`

My desired result is:

`array('carr','car','arc','ra','c','rr')`

i.e. filtering out 'abc','do','aa' because I wish to filter out words that:

1. don't contain `a`, `c` or `r`
2. contain more/multiple `a`, `c`, or `r` than I have in array1.

I have tried `array_filter()`, but I don't seem to be able to make it work.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include your best, failed coding attempt using `array_filter()` so that I can justify uv'ing your question -- which I found fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this:

Count how many times each letter occurs in your first array, using `array_count_values`.

Then in your array_filter callback function, split each word into individual letters, and also count how many times each of them occurs. Then loop over those counted letters. If the current letter does not occur in your letter-count-array, or its count is greater than that in your letter-count-array, return false.

```
$letters = ['a','c','r','r'];
$words = ['carr','car','arc','ra','c','abc','do','aa','rr'];

$letterCounts = array_count_values($letters);

$filtered = array_filter($words, function($word) use ($letterCounts) {
    $wordLetterCounts = array_count_values(mb_str_split($word));
    foreach($wordLetterCounts as $wordLetter => $count) {
        if(!isset($letterCounts[$wordLetter]) || $letterCounts[$wordLetter] < $count) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});

var_dump($filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you iterate the array of words, you can iterate the array of letters and make single-letter replacements.  If all letters in the word are consumed, the word is saved.

A regular expression isn't actually necessary because the letter is literal, but `preg_replace()` offers a limiting parameter and `str_replace()` doesn't.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/u4FI1))

```
$needles = ['a','c','r','r'];
$haystacks = ['carr','car','arc','ra','c','abc','do','aa','rr', 'rrr'];

$result = [];
foreach ($haystacks as $i => $haystack) {
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        $haystack = preg_replace("/$needle/", '', $haystack, 1);
    }
    if (!$haystack) {
        $result[] = $haystacks[$i];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

---

The above can actually be boiled down to this: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dG1kc))

```
$regexes = array_map(fn($v) => "/$v/", $needles);
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $haystacks,
        fn($hay) => !preg_replace($regexes, '', $hay, 1)
    )
);
```